# interpolation/distribution of data from a "time range" dataframe1 to a "time window" dataframe2

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, data-science

This is a problem about calculating the mean of bus passengers for each minute of the day, given a DF1 list of bus trip start and finish times (hours:minutes), to a DF2 containing a "time window" from 3:01AM to 3:00AM(next day) of any day (date agnostic) as its index.

DF1 contains data from each trip, built with the following code:

```
start = [pd.to_datetime('03:01'),pd.to_datetime('03:08'),pd.to_datetime('03:06')]
finish = [pd.to_datetime('03:11'),pd.to_datetime('03:13'),pd.to_datetime('03:16')]
df1 = pd.DataFrame()
df1['passengers'] = [10, 15, 20]
df1['t1'] = start
df1['t2'] = finish
df1
```

Resulting in:

```
            passengers  t1                  t2
0           10          2019-07-20 03:01:00 2019-07-20 03:11:00
1           15          2019-07-20 03:08:00 2019-07-20 03:13:00
2           20          2019-07-20 03:06:00 2019-07-20 03:16:00
```

DF2 contains a "time window" from 3:01AM to 3AM (as if the regular 24h were shifted 3h forward), like this:

```
cuthour = '03:00' # <--- user input
cuthour = pd.to_datetime(cuthour)
idx = pd.date_range(cuthour+pd.to_timedelta('1min'),'23:59', freq='T').append(pd.date_range('00:00',cuthour,freq='T'))
df2  = pd.DataFrame(index=idx)
df2['passengers'] = 0  #initialize with zeros
```

Resulting in df2.info():

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
DatetimeIndex: 1440 entries, 2019-07-20 03:01:00 to 2019-07-20 03:00:00
Data columns (total 1 columns):
pessoas    1440 non-null int64
dtypes: int64(1)
```

What I want is a DF2 with the mean of passengers/minute of any date, like this:

```
2019-07-20 03:01:00 1.0
2019-07-20 03:02:00 1.0
2019-07-20 03:03:00 1.0
2019-07-20 03:04:00 1.0
2019-07-20 03:05:00 1.0
2019-07-20 03:06:00 1.5
2019-07-20 03:07:00 1.5
2019-07-20 03:08:00 2.0
2019-07-20 03:09:00 2.0
2019-07-20 03:10:00 2.0
2019-07-20 03:11:00 2.5
2019-07-20 03:12:00 2.5
2019-07-20 03:13:00 2.0
2019-07-20 03:14:00 2.0
2019-07-20 03:15:00 2.0
2019-07-20 03:16:00 0.0
2019-07-20 03:17:00 0.0
...
```

But instead I got this:

```
2019-07-20 03:01:00 1.0
2019-07-20 03:02:00 1.0
2019-07-20 03:03:00 1.0
2019-07-20 03:04:00 1.0
2019-07-20 03:05:00 1.0
2019-07-20 03:06:00 3.0
2019-07-20 03:07:00 3.0
2019-07-20 03:08:00 6.0
2019-07-20 03:09:00 6.0
2019-07-20 03:10:00 6.0
2019-07-20 03:11:00 5.0
2019-07-20 03:12:00 5.0
2019-07-20 03:13:00 2.0
2019-07-20 03:14:00 2.0
2019-07-20 03:15:00 2.0
2019-07-20 03:16:00 0.0
2019-07-20 03:17:00 0.0
...
```

Using this code:

```
def calcmean(x):
    ir = pd.date_range(x.t1,x.t2,freq='T')
    lir = len(ir)-1
    mp = x.passengers/lir
    df2.loc[df2.index.isin(ir)] = df2.loc[df2.index.isin(ir)] + mp

df1.apply(calcmean, axis=1)    
df2
```

Of course the mean passengers/minute of each trip are summing with the previous mean of each minute instead of finding the new mean. I couldn't find a way to recalculate the mean.

For a better view of the data:

```
        mean of...              TOTAL   total
HH:MM   trip1   trip2   trip3   MEAN    sum
03:01   1                       1       1
03:02   1                       1       1
03:03   1                       1       1
03:04   1                       1       1
03:05   1                       1       1
03:06   1               2       1.5     3
03:07   1               2       1.5     3
03:08   1       3       2       2       6
03:09   1       3       2       2       6
03:10   1       3       2       2       6
03:11           3       2       2.5     5
03:12           3       2       2.5     5
03:13                   2       2       2
03:14                   2       2       2
03:15                   2       2       2


trip1 mean = 10 passengers / 10 minutes = 1 passenger/minute
trip2 mean = 15 passengers / 5 minutes = 3 passengers/minute
trip3 mean = 20 passengers / 10 minutes = 2 passengers/minute
```

I want the TOTAL MEAN, I got the total sum.

Comment: why trip 2 has 3x6 while your passengers in df1 shows 15 (and 2x11 where it should be 20)

Comment: This df1 is just an example. I represented the data as in last table, wrongly considering start minute as part of the time range (df1.t2 - df1.t1). Now I fixed it.

Comment: Now from your df how can one tell that the distribution is equal? what if you have 11 passengers  in index 0, how would you distribute them?

Comment: You mean a trip with a start time at 03h01min, a finish time at 03h02min and 11 passengers transported?
That would be 11 passengers per minute at 03:01AM, if the day or days in question had only this trip at this time. But that would be only an imaginary situation, not happening in practice.